# reverse link list using recursion

Tags: c++

I am trying to reverse a link list using recursion. I have written a function "reverse(node* ptr) for this
I am getting output as 40 40 20 while i expect output to be 40 , 20 , 10. 
below is the code posted.

```
class list {
    //some code;

    void reverse()
    {
        node* temp = new node;
        temp =first;
        reverse(temp);
        temp =NULL;
        delete temp;
    }

    void reverse(node* ptr) {


        if(ptr->next != NULL)
        {
           ptr =ptr->next;
           reverse(ptr);
        }
        cout << ptr->data << endl;
    }
    // some code;
};

int main()
{
    list ll;
    ll.insert(18);
    ll.insert(20);
    ll.insert(40);
    ll.display();
    ll.reverse();
    return 0;
}
```

please suggest what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: `node* temp = new node; temp =first;` causes memory leak, you allocate a new node, and then you "forget" about it lose its address [note that doesn't address your question, it's a different issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get rid of the line `ptr =ptr->next;`.

The main objective is to print all the nodes that come after the current node before printing value of the current node. So simply a call to `reverse(ptr->next)` followed by a `cout<<ptr->data<<endl` should suffice, since the first call takes care of all nodes after `ptr`. There is no need to advance the pointer as we want to print the current node at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Before even talking about the linked list, there is a major problem with your code:

```
void reverse()
{
    node* temp = new node;
    temp =first;
    reverse(temp);
    temp =NULL;
    delete temp;
}
```

You allocate space for a `node` and then change what it is pointing to, to `first`. This means the memory you allocated will be leaked. Not only that but you then set it to NULL and then try to free it. You can't free NULL!

I believe you simply meant:

```
void reverse()
{
    reverse(first);
}
```

Simple. On to the linked list:

```
if(ptr->next != NULL)
{
    ptr =ptr->next;
    reverse(ptr);
}
```

You set `ptr` to the next element so when `reverse()` returns it will be one element ahead. I believe you meant:

```
if(ptr->next != NULL)
{
    reverse(ptr->next);
}
```

Comment: Ok...

for the second I changed it :

void reverse(node* ptr) {
if (ptr->next != NULL) {
    reverse(ptr); 
}
count << ptr->data << endl;
}
still I am getting same issue.